# what exactly is Option (⌥)+click on mac?

Tags: mac

what is Option (⌥) + mouse left button click on a non-top (focused) window in OSX?

On linux i use alt+click to raise windows. And sometimes on an mac, i press ⌥+click instead of simply clicking a back window, because of muscle memory. So not pressing it is not an option. I know i will continue to press this by mistake every now and then.

What happens on the mac is that it does raise the window i clicked, but the previously top window is now hidden. If I do not remember which app it was and its corresponding icon on the launcher, i will never see that window again!

What exactly is this shortcut and is there a way to disable it?

Comment: Opt/click used that way is the system-wide shortcut for "switch to the clicked app & hide the current app". I'm almost certain you're going to have to learn not to do that, but I'm not going to post this as an answer in case someone comes up with a smart `defaults write` that can do it. Perhaps of incidental interest is it has a 'partner' Cmd/click; which is "act on this window **without** bringing the app to the font".

Comment: nice! thanks for sharing the cmd+click one! now i am wondering if there is a way to change my defaults on OSX to simulate the setup i use on X11... clicks=cmd+click (do not raise), and opt+click=regular click(raise but don't act).

Comment: Not that I'm one to complain usually [cough, cough], but since we lost Steve & gained Tim, a lot of the internal consistency has gone. What does remain is that universal shortcuts are really hard to override. You might get something like that to work with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which is oft-touted, though I've never used it myself.

Comment: Karabiner is dead after OSX11. They broke all the APIs it used. I was a very happy user until then. Now they have a lighweight version called karabiner-elements, that do work with OSX11+ but is much, much less capable :(

Comment: As of 2021, Karabiner is not dead and is fully functional (with the new brand Karabiner-Elements).